# В firefox 52.6 esr на winXP проблема с обработкой ответа от сервера (json)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Суть проблемы: делаю обычный jquery ajax запрос, ответ приходит все хорошо,кроме того что если не пропустить ответ через JSON.parse(response), то в firefox 52.6 esr и yandex browser на winXP ответ будет строковой переменной, а не объектом. В других браузерах и ос все работает и без парсинга. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Опубликуйте js таким образом, что б можно было повторить проблему без особых усилий. `<html><script>....`. Так... с JSON поддержкой в браузерах ещё не столкнулся.

Comment: Попробуйте при запросе явно указывать `responseType`. Также надо посмотреть, что сервер отдает.

Comment: Ответ от сервера: 
  `  {result: [{name: "Безработные", title: "Безработные", recId: 
    "RLifeEvent_40008"},…], hasError: false,…}

    errorMessage:null
    hasError:false
    result:[{name: "Безработные", title: "Безработные", recId: 
    "RLifeEvent_40008"},…] `